# Why is my React stylesheet media query not working?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am connecting an external stylesheet to my React component, and I have a media query and I intend the logo to have a height of 100vh when the screen width is less than 300px. However this media query is ignored and only the original styles apply. I tried adding the css directly in the HTML file using the style tag. Here is the relevant code:

Logo.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Logo.css";

export default class Logo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img 
        alt=""
        className="Logo"
        src="../logo.png"
      />
    );
  };  
};
```

Logo.css

```
.Logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 42vw;
  bottom: calc(50vh + 4vw);
  height: 16vw;
};

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .Logo {
    height: 100vh;
  };
};
```

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: @AdamAzad Inspect element and then used toggle device toolbar. Simulated using samsung galaxy fold.

Comment: @KotetsuChan galaxy fold's screen width might be larger than 300px. Did you try with a different value?

Comment: @ozgur On chrome it said the simulated width is 280px, which is less than 300.

Comment: @KotetsuChan check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491645/media-query-syntax-for-reactjs

Comment: @ozgur I already tried that it said window.matchMedia is not defined,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hooks in react:

```
import React from "react";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

export default function Logo() {
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-aspect-ratio: 1/1)'
  });
  let logo = {};

  if (isDesktop) {
    logo = {
      position: "absolute",
      left: "42vw",
      bottom: "calc(50vh + 4vw)",
      height: "16vw"
    };
  } else {
    logo = {
      position: "absolute",
      left: "38vw",
      bottom: "calc(50vh + 6vw)",
      height: "24vw",
    };
  };

  return (
    <img 
      alt=""
      style={logo}
      src="../logo.png"
    />
  );
};
```

Remember to download useMediaQuery by typing
`npm install react-responsive --save`
into the command line.

Comment: is this the correct way to do it? why the style sheet doen't work? please if you can answer those question to me

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this to the head section of your code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Is your browser zoom-ed at different than 100% level ? If so, can you zoom to 100% (Ctrl+MouseWheel) and try again?