# How do I add a Media Query to a React CSS object?

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, react-css-modules

Currently I have this:

```
const ButtonStyles = {
    color: 'red',
}
```

But I want to add a Media Query for mobile, would it look something like this?:

```
const ButtonStyles = {
    color: 'red',
    '@media (max-width: 900px)': {
        color: 'blue',
    }
}
```

If the syntax is not in this format, then how is it supposed to be done?

Comment: Have you tried the options suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491645/media-query-syntax-for-reactjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491645/media-query-syntax-for-reactjs) You cannot use Media queries with react css objects. You must use stylesheets with class names or other external modules like styled components.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try.

https://github.com/kasinskas/react-native-media-query
Work just like RN StyleSheet, but with queries.

https://github.com/yocontra/react-responsive
Work with functions inside regular RN StyleSheet

An eg. with natives StyleSheet, Platform and React-Responsive and variables.

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';

export const STYLES = StyleSheet.create({

  content: (setup) => {
    const justifyTo = setup?.justify ? setup.justify : 'flex-start';

    return {
      justifyContent: justifyTo,
      ...Platform.select({
        web: {
          width: useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 767 }) ? '100vw' : '70vw',

          maxWidth: 1280,
          marginHorizontal: 'auto',
          marginVertical: 'auto',
        },
      }),
    };
  }

});
```